# Magento2: filter product collection by custom attribute

Tags: magento2.3, collection, product-collection

I am using Magento ver. 2.3.6.

I want to filter product collection by custom product attribute and I am using below code:-

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Vendor_CustomModule::customCollection" type="Vendor\CustomModule\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    
    public function aroundSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection) 
    {
        $result       = $proceed($collection);
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $dir          = $subject->getCurrentDirection();        
        
        $subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('country_of_manufacture', ['eq' => 'IN']);          
        return $result;
    }   
}
```

Above code filter the product collection only on category page, I want this filter result in whole website, including, new product, featured product, bestseller products, realted products, upsell products, crosssell products and search result.

Please let me know where I add my custom filter in product collection, So filter result will show on whole website products.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can achieve this from one singe place.
But here is how I did it. I hope I covered all the places.

First, I create my own class / method that applies an extra filter to a product collection.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;

class RestrictionApplier
{
    /**
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    public function apply(Collection $collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter( 'country_of_manufacture', ['eq' => 'IN']);
    }
}
```

then I used this class / method in `after` plugins for the following methods:

- `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link::getProductCollection`
- `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList::createCollection`

and in an observer on the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection`

The plugins look like this:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product;

use [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\RestrictionApplier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection;

class LinkPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var RestrictionApplier
     */
    private $restrictionApplier;
   
    /**
     * ProductListPlugin constructor.
     * @param RestrictionApplier $restrictionApplier
     */
    public function __construct(RestrictionApplier $restrictionApplier)
    {
        $this->restrictionApplier = $restrictionApplier;
    }

    /**
     * @param Link $subject
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return Collection
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetProductCollection(Link $subject, Collection $collection)
    {
        $this->restrictionApplier->apply($collection);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

for the observer is similar

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    $this->restrictionApplier->apply($collection);
}
```

Comment: No result noticed after add this code in my custom plugin, Please can you simplify this answer and I am checking again if I miss anything in my code.

Comment: you can check if your plugin gets called. Put a log in it or something

Comment: Yes plugin is not working. I using this code in `etc/frontend/di.xml`    http://prntscr.com/vd9az4

please let me know if any issue in this

Comment: Any comments on my plugin call issue?

Comment: @Marius the filter works like charm but the layered navigation is having the same filters

Comment: I think that this works for mysql fulltext search. Not sure if it works for elasticsearch. It's been a while since I did this. I forgot things.